# Function PHP trader_stochrsi returning incorrect values

Tags: php, pecl

Can anybody help me? Why does the stochrsi trader function not return the "similar / next" K and D values of the Stochrsi indicator to the chart? I believe the input parameters are right, I'm passing an array of closed prices and periods 14, 3 (D), 3 (K) as the function requests.

My array `$data['close']` is correct

```
public function stochrsi($data)
{
   $stochrsi_trend = trader_stochrsi($data['close'], 14, 3, 3, TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA);

   $fast_k = current($stochrsi_trend);

   echo 'Array K:';
   vdp($fast_k);

   $fast_d = end($stochrsi_trend);

   echo 'Array D:';
   vdp($fast_d);

   echo 'Last position K: ';
   $k = end($fast_k);
   vdp($k);

   echo 'Last position D: ';
   $d = end($fast_d);
   vdp($d);
}
```

Values in Chart (see that 31 and 16 are well away from the debug values):
[image]

Debug:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Do you have some answer for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I did not find bro solution, I had to disable the StochRSI indicator and only work with the Stoch and RSI separate.

Comment: Hmm, this is really bad. I am trying also to become this also since 2 days, but the only one goal I have is to become the right fastd (blue line) in this way: trader_stochrsi($prices['close'], 14, 14, 3, TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA); , where in the prices array there are 168 entries. The fastk (red line) is still wrong.

Comment: I have a theory, maybe you have to spend the same amount of prices as the chart to get the exact result with this indicator.

Comment: How did you sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$rsi = trader_rsi($closes, 14);
$stochrsi = trader_stoch($rsi, $rsi, $rsi, 14, 3, TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA, 3, TRADER_MA_TYPE_SMA);
```